# Aligning with flexbox in react native

Tags: react-native, alignment, react-native-flexbox

I have this screen on my app which corresponds to this code

```
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
          <Chrono style={styles.svgStyle} fill="blue"/>
          <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}>Add</Button>
      </View>
    )

  }
}

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginBottom: 200,
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
  svgStyle: {
    height: 180,
    width: 180
  },
  buttonStyle: {
   height: 20,
   width: 100,
   backgroundColor: '#00aeef',
   borderWidth: 5,
   borderRadius: 15
  }
};
```

[image]

I would like the chrono to be positioned in the center and the button at the end of the column (screen). 
I am struggling to do that with flexbox as I understand there is no align-self property for aligning accross the main axis.

What is the good way to go to achieve this ?

----EDIT---- 
the component(called Starter) above is wrapped in a view with the following style :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Starter />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
<View style={styles.containerStyle}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, jusifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center }}>
    <Chrono style={styles.svgStyle} fill="blue"/>
  <View>
  <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}>Add</Button>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `Chrono` component within an absolute position `View` that pins to the edges of the container. You can then position the `Button` component as if the `Chrono` component isn't there using `justifyContent: 'flex-end'` and `marginBottom` (as long as it's rendered *after* `Chrono` and its wrapper.

```
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
          <View style={styles.chronoWrapperStyle}>
              <Chrono style={styles.svgStyle} fill="blue"/>
          </View>
          <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}>Add</Button>
      </View>
    )

  }
}

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginBottom: 200,
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
  chronoWrapperStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  svgStyle: {
    height: 180,
    width: 180
  },
  buttonStyle: {
   justifyContent: 'flex-end',
   marginBottom: 20,
   height: 20,
   width: 100,
   backgroundColor: '#00aeef',
   borderWidth: 5,
   borderRadius: 15
  }
};
```